# AWS RDS can't connect security group

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

This is question is related to an earlier one I asked, but more specific and hopefully easier to answer.

Essentially, I can't connect to my RDS instance. I tried in my SQL editor (datagrips) and also by pinging the server on the console. Comments on my previous question led me to believe that my problem has to do with the security group. Upon investigation, however, everything seems to be in order--my security group has an inbound rule that should allow all inbound access.

Security Group:
[image]

Console Ping:
[image]

What is going on here?

EDIT:

It was pointed out that all inbound access does not mean what I thought it did. However I also tried allowing inbound access for my specific IP with still no luck.

Here is the inbound rule for My IP:

[image]

EDIT 2:

Not sure what this means but it's not timing out on the EC2...

[image]

See comments for context?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry for not responding. I still need to install the mysql client. Not sure how to do that on the EC2. This whole process has been a bit overwhelming for me and perhaps it would be helpful if I knew more about AWS. Are there any good resources to learn more about AWS?  I feel like I need to know more about what's going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> inbound rule that should allow all inbound access

**It does not**. It only allows inbound traffic from SG with id of `sg-ea3...`. This means that you can't connect to it from home, work etc. To allow all inbound access the source should be `0.0.0.0/0`, but it would be better to have your exact home/work ip address `<your-ip-address>/32`.

Comment: I tried adding an inbound rule for My IP but that didn't work either. I'll edit my post to include that inbound rule screenshot.

Comment: @JohnSorensen In that case, maybe your RDS is not publicly accessible? Can you check this setting in RDS console, or maybe its deployed in private subnet, not accessible from the internet?

Comment: Under "Security," "Yes" is marked for Publicly Accessible. Could it be something on my end?

Comment: Can you spin up an ec2 instance in same vpc as the rds and check connectivity from it?

Comment: I'm new to AWS so it might take me a minute but I'll try that

Comment: Ok it seems like I have a EC2 instance running though I'm not sure if I am hooked into the same VPC or how to change that

Comment: if you don't use the instance, its good idea to terminate it. You have to check network settings of your VPC and the RDS.

Comment: Ok, it looks like they are in the same VPC--the VPC ID's of the EC2 instance and the RDS are the same. (is that an indication that they are in the same VPC?) How do I ping the RDS from the EC2 instance?

Comment: @JohnSorensen You have to ssh to it, and can try with `nc` as before. Also make sure you modify RDS security groups to allow connections from other IPs then your own.

Comment: Not exactly sure what's going on, but after setting up at EC2, I changed my RDS security group to include the EC2 IP and then was able to ping it on the EC2 terminal. I had to use the ping command as `nc` didn't work (perhaps becuase my EC2 is Linux?) I'll edit question to include results.

Comment: @JohnSorensen can you install `mysql` client on the ec2 instance try connecting with it?

Comment: Yeah I'll try that next. Did the ping thing work? Not sure if it's even the right command...